# Setup Laragon with PHP and Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug, laragon

I have an issue with Laragon PHP and Xdebug.

**PHP = 8.1.9, Xdebug = 3.1.5**

The server was working fine after setting up Xdebug and trying to listen for Xdebug, but when I'm not debugging the server won't start and keeps loading (PHP apps and scripts not working).

**php.ini :**

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

**launch.json :**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where did you place the xdebug.dll file on your disk?

Comment: "Launch Built-in web server" dont think you can put xdebug in there, you have to launch via a external web server configured with PHP which is properly configured with xdebug

Comment: xdebug dll path "php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

Comment: laragon is preconfigured with php mysql and nginx with virtual hosts